# Pull in an "Include" file based on a WordPress Category ID

Tags: categories, include, template-include

Here's what I am trying to achieve: when a category page is loaded then, based upn the ID of that category, an "include" file is loaded.

I believe that the below would work for some limited text, but I would prefer to load an "include" file b/c it will have multiple paragraphs and I feel it is better to manage that way.

```
   <?php
    $catarray = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    foreach ($catarray as $cat) {
        $catid = $cat->term_id;

        if ($catid == 10) {
          echo 'TEXT HERE'; // I prefer a PHP Include File 
        }
        if ($catid == 7) {
          echo 'ANOTHER TEXT';
        }

    }
    ?>
```

So, my question would be - what would I need to do to replace the "echo" string? Would it be simply:

```
include get_theme_file_path( '/subdir/text-to-enter-in-the-category-10.php' );
```

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean but this might work [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)